# System js map doesn't work

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs, primeng

Maybe I am dumb but system js always gives so much pain, although its so nice that I don't want to use anything else.

My system js config is this:

```
System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            primeng:{
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        map: {
          primeng: 'node_modules/primeng'
        }
    });
```

Primeng is being imported like this:

```
import {Accordion} from "primeng/primeng";
import {AccordionTab} from "primeng/primeng";
```

This is a ts file which gets compiled in js by gulp and then used by my index.html.

But in my terminal I get error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'primeng/primeng'
```

If anyone has any idea, please solve this

Comment: That is a typescript error. Are you sure the compiler can reach the `primeng.d.ts` definition file?

Comment: No, how to define that in typings.json?

Comment: It should find it, when it is in `node_modules/primeng/primeng.d.ts`

Comment: primeng.d.ts is a local file in node_modules/primeng. But primeng is not present on github, so I don't know how to use that?

Comment: My present typings.json looks like this:

{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2"
  }
}

Comment: @PierreDuc - Please answer how to include this local .d.ts file in the above typings.json

Comment: I've been struggling with the same thing. I think the problem is having module resolution set to 'node'. What happens if you install this package as a local npm module? npm install --save /path/to.file. The alternative would be to use classic module resolution but I'm sure Angular2 will explode.

Comment: Yeah...I think more flexibility and generality is needed in both typescript and systemjs. The documentation is also not that good, although both of them are grt libraries.

Comment: In the meantime you can use barrels to make your imports a bit cleaner: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

We have to reference the type definition in the component's .ts file itself. So at the top of my component file I have to write this:

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/primeng/components/accordion/accordion.d.ts"/>
```