# How to define local .d.ts file definition in typings.json file

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs, primeng

I am developing an angular2 application. Where I use systemjs and typescript.

I have a local node module named primeng that I want to use in my project. I am writing correct systemjs config which maps to the location of primeng.

I import primeng in one of my components.

But when I compile my app with gulp I get error TS2307:Cannot find module 'primeng'.

I got to know that we have to mention the definition file of any package in typings.json. So I tried to search primeng like this- typings search primeng. But I cannot find that. So I looked into primeng module and there is primeng.d.ts file.

So I don't know how to include this definition in typings.json. I hope after writing that, my problem will be solved.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System js map doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437726/system-js-map-doesnt-work)

Comment: no duplicate, defined only once.

Comment: You already asked the same question already - why open a new one?

Comment: That question is for systemjs maps. This is for defining typescript config. Although the answer maybe same(to me it seems like typescript issue), but both are different questions.

Comment: Did you try to reference the typings file like this: `///<reference path="node_modules/primeng/primeng.d.ts"/>` at the top of the file where you do the import?

Comment: Is primeng a module created by you? Meaning, can you change it?

Comment: @rinukkusu- Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @rinukkusu's comment worked for you, adding this reference to their type definitions int he node_modules folder:

```
///<reference path="node_modules/primeng/primeng.d.ts"/>
```

If there were type definitions in the registry you would do this:

```
typings search primeng
```

And add the one that you want to use, probably from 'dt' source definitely typed (this doesn't exist so it won't work, might should use the `--global` flag):

```
typings install dt~primeng
```

Since you have primeng installed using npm, you shouldn't need that if you're `tsconfig.json` file has this:

```
moduleResolution: "node"
```

Comment: I already wrote this in tscconfig. But still I had to write what @rinukkusu told me to do.